# Окончить или закончить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, глаголы

Как правильно говорить "закончить вуз" или "окончить вуз"?

Comment: Спасибо всем за детальный ответ !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В русском языке слова "окончить" и "закончить" - синонимы. Поэтому, если речь идет о каком-нибудь деле, то можно говорить и так, и так. Если же речь идет об учебном заведении, то употребляется только "окончить".
Примеры: *"закончить работу", "окончить университет".*

Comment: На основании чего Вы делаете такой вывод?

Answer (score 7):

Это синонимы. Словарь сочетаемости оба варианта дает с пометой разговорное. Я думаю, книжный вариант будет "окончить (закончить) обучение в вузе".

Answer (score 7):

Интересно, что в произведениях столетней давности вместо "окончить/закончить университет" употреблялось только выражение "окончить курс в университете". Со временем оно упростилось до "окончить университет", а потом уже стало употребляться и "закончить университет".

В современном языке эти слова в данном значении употребляются равноправно.

Ну, может, "*окончить*" совсем чуть-чуть отдает стариной.

Comment: Разрешите чуточку поправить. В 19 веке и потом еще довольно долго люди "старого времени" также  говорили : *кончил курс* (... в университете, в Академии, в гимназии, наук, обучения и др.) Приведу смешную цитату :

>А. И. Герцен. Долг прежде всего (1851) Степушку никогда бы не решились они отправить на службу, отдать в чужие руки; Левушку, напротив, родители не жалели, и как только он **кончил курс своего воспитания**, то есть научился читать по-русски и писать вопреки всем правилам орфографии, его отправили в Петербург.

В Нацкорпусе 113 примеров - "кончил курс" и 74 - "окончил курс".

Comment: **yupaz**, в этом есть большая доля истины. 
Но смотреть надо до какого-то времени. Скажем - XIX век. 
И там я наблюдаю следующую картину. Закончил/окончил университет - единичные примеры, но присутствуют. "Окончил курс" - да, очень много. Но 
"Закончил курс в университете" - тоже почти не встречается.

Это очень примерный анализ, ибо не все формы проверены. И тем не менее...
"Закончить курс"  - это, видимо, общая формулировка... Хоть для университета, хоть для школы дрессированых тараканов. Не отменяет ни "окончить университет", "ни закончить".

Answer (score 3):

Университет можно только окончить, (не закончить), так как диплом выдаётся об окончании ВУЗа.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше - "закончить". "Окончить" в данном значении возможно, но сохраняет налет разговорности.

//------------

Мою уверенность несколько поколебал yupaz своим комментарием. Именно так: поколебал. Не переубедил..

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютное большинство источников рекомендует говорить **кончил или окончил школу, университет** и т. п., но не **закончил**. В этом значении слова **кончил** и **окончил** синонимичны.

В некоторых словарях (например, в толковом словаре Кузнецова) можно встретить выражения: **Как давно ты закончил школу?**, **Закончил музыкальную школу по классу скрипки** и т.п., но в данном случае лучше следовать рекомендациям большинства источников.

В [словаре ошибок русского языка](https://common_mistakes.academic.ru/77/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) говорится следующее:

> А вот если речь идет о завершении курса наук, то для этого годится только глагол окончить: **Я окончил** (не закончил) **школу два года назад**.

Ещё, для примера, ответ справочной службы Грамота.ру на [вопрос 227149](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=227149):

> Как правильно : ОКОНЧИТЬ (КОНЧИТЬ, ЗАКОНЧИТЬ) школу?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Верно: *окончить, кончить*.

Answer (score 0):

Глаголы "закончить или окончить" в контексте разговора о получении высшего образования - неграмотно употреблять.
 Это говорит о  прерывании, прекращении учёбы (всего-навсего) по какой-то причине.
 Мы ВЫПУСКАЕМСЯ из Университета. Так и при переводе на английский. 
 "Graduated from The University",
 но "Finished School"

Comment: Хотелось бы более аргументированного обоснования неграмотности. А ссылки на английские шаблоны говорят скорее о незнании родного языка

Comment: В 187*-м, милостивый государь, ***окончил*** оную! [А. И. Куприн. Погибшая сила (1900)] ― Только, видите ли… вам не совсем бы удобно было говорить мне об этом, потому что я сам… ***окончил*** академию годом позже вас, но… должен признаться, что не видел вас ни разу. [А. И. Куприн. Погибшая сила (1900)]

Comment: Про Линтварева было слышно, что он ***окончил*** курс в университете, увлечен земскими делами, профессиональным образованием. И. А. Бунин. Учитель (1894)

Comment: Сам он окончил ***одесский*** университет, потом ― земледельческую академию в Цюрихе. [В. Г. Короленко. Письма (1893)]  ←…→

Comment: PS Привет англичанам.