# Почему нельзя "закончить школу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ответ Грамоты.ру:  В значении 'пройти какой-либо курс обучения, завершить обучение где-либо' употребляется **только глагол окончить**: окончить школу, вуз, университет, курсы и т. п.

Тем не менее пользователи одинаково часто школу "оканчивают и заканчивают".

И все-таки почему "закончить школу" - это неправильно? Может быть, приставка ЗА придает глаголу какой-то нежелательный смысловой оттенок? И как вообще можно определить область применения этих двух глаголов?

Примечание

Вопрос уже обсуждался на форуме в 2011 году, но без обоснования правильности той или другой формы
[Окончить или закончить?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/206/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Как пишут на портале «Русский язык», глаголы закончить и окончить синонимичны и взаимозаменяемы в значении «довести до конца, завершить». Таким образом, одинаково корректны варианты: закончить работу и окончить работу, закончить рассказ и окончить рассказ, закончить съемки и окончить съемки.

Однако в значении «пройти какой-либо курс обучения, завершить обучение где-либо» употребляется только глагол окончить: окончить школу, университет, институт, курсы и тому подобное."

[Как правильно: окончить или закончить вуз?](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/45949-kak-pravilno-okonchit-ili-zakonchit-vuz/)

Comment: Остается только понять, почему "закончить школу" стало ненормированным. Оба выражения  имеют примерно равную частотность употребления, значит, это волевое решение наших грамматиков?  А такие решения нужно объяснять и для этого, скорее всего, следует анализировать значение приставок ЗА и О.

Comment: Как по мне, это одно из тех правил, что живо больше "на бумаге", нежели в реальной речи даже грамотных и образованных людей.

Comment: А мне всё-таки кажется, что "закончить курс обучения" - это правильно, а закончить школу - не очень правильно. Ведь здесь, скорее, перенос  по смежности, а при переносе  приставка ЗА не очень подходит, так как " закончить школу" звучит как, например, закончить строительство школы. Как вы думаете?

Comment: Мне кажется, что "закончить" обозначает привести к полному завершению, предполагающему, что больше  это действие не будет продолжаться. "Окончить" же имеет значение "завершить определенный этап действия", которое может быть продолжено на ином уровне, в ином направлении

Comment: Обоснование тут вряд ли может быть. Это вроде кофе среднего рода: считать разговорным, нерекомендуемым или грубоошибочным? Вот, считают разговорным.

Comment: *Остается только понять, почему "закончить школу" стало ненормированным. * - Не так. Оно никогда **не было нормативным** (по причине, далекой от грамматической обусловленности, чисто традиция - см. мой ответ). Но сейчас есть шанс сприобрести нормативность, пусть пока и частичную.

Comment: @behemothus Отличный ответ. :--)

Answer (score 2):

РАЗМЫШЛЕНИЕ НА ТЕМУ

При решении трудных вопросов я часто обращаюсь к "Толковому словарю словообразовательных частиц" Ефремовой и сравниваю значение приставок.

Вот приставка ЗА, она интересна тем, что может обозначать как начало, так и завершение действие: петь - запеть, шифровать - зашифровать. Она как бы обозначает границы линейного процесса, протекающего во времени.

Вот приставка О, она интересна тем, что чаще обозначает действие, направленное вокруг предмета: обегать, обрызгать, обучить.

Окончить - это как бы довести предмет до полного (всестороннего) конца, а закончить - это завершить начатый процесс, например закончить предложение (не окончить же).

Поэтому курс обучения мы начинаем и заканчиваем, как и предложение. **Начать школу, как здесь уже говорилось, мы не можем, поэтому не должны ее и заканчивать.
Итак, закончить учебу, но окончить школу.** Так считает Грамота.ру, и мне эта точка зрения кажется правильной.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, "Грамота" вслед за многими другими "рекомендателями" несколько погорячилась. У закончить есть нужное значение, так что в претензии на единственность сочетания с окончить не особо верится. 
Многочисленные сомнения, массовые "ошибки" авторов и отсутствие общеприемлемых строгих объяснений - тому свидетельство.

Тут, видимо другое.

Сложившийся стереотип (не ставший пока нормой), что "окончить" не несет грубоватого оттенка.

Исторически "окончить" было единственно (из двух) возможным, жто да. Но это была стилистическая норма, не грамматический/семантический императив. Зато наряду с ним употреблялось и просто "кончить".

Вот есть такое объяснение.

1. Глагол закончил употребляется для обозначения завершения действия в широком значении. Глагол окончил по смыслу связан с завершением процесса обучения.
2. Глагол закончил не образует устойчивых сочетаний и может быть использован в любой соответствующей его значению речевой конструкции. Глагол окончил входит в устойчивые сочетания наряду с существительными, называющими какое-либо учебное заведение.

   Подробнее: http://thedifference.ru/kak-pishetsya-pravilno-okonchil-ili-zakonchil/

**Другими словами, устоявшееся употребление - и ничего более.**

*Справедливости ради. Там де есть и третий пункт:
3.    Глагол закончил нельзя заменить глаголом окончил без изменения смысла предложения.
С которым я совсем не согласен. Он противоречит явно декларируемому подходу, что "окончить" - это более узкое значение для "закончить". Но разве частное значение нельзя заменить общим без потери смысла? Что-то перемудрили... Так что третий пункт я не принимаю, но это не мешает мне принимать первые два*.

Answer (score 0):

Почему нельзя “закончить школу”?

Чтобы **закончить** (тоже, что и **окончить**) учебное заведение, сперва надо его **начать**. Но так же (начал школу) не говорят, предпочитая **пошёл в институт**, **начал учиться в школе**. Правильно было бы не употреблять совсем эту корявую "двухходовку", изо всех сил пытаясь экономить на словах и буквах. Подозреваю, что в этом смысле **окончить** предпочтительней **закончить** только из-за длины.

Правильно: начинать учиться в школе; заканчивать обучение; получать образование в вузе.

Comment: Начать что-то надо в любом случае. И то что потом будет окончено, и то, что закончено. Как объяснение не очень подходит.